# Unexpected token ILLEGAL - javascript error в Google Chrome

Tags: webkit, google-chrome, javascript

Доброго времени суток,

Для XHR формируется ответ:

```
echo "FCKeditorAPI.GetInstance('FCKeditor_DESC').SetHTML('$DESC');";
```

Здесь $DESC - произвольный текст из MySql.
На стороне клиента данные из XHR исполняются напрямую:

```
eval(data);
```

Как раз на этой строчке появляется ошибка: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL. htmlspecialchars() не дал результата. Ошибка появляется только в Chrome; FF, IE и Opera скушали текст нормально.

Comment: Ну так Вы поймите, в какой момент происходит ошибка!

Вместо eval сделайте обычный вывод строки, убедитесь, что строка сформирована правильно. Скорее всего, в ней будет ошибка — тогда ищите баг на стороне php-скрипта.

*Вообще не понимаю, как, по-вашему, мы должны телепатически отловить такую ошибку…*

Comment: @dagen niger Вместо создания уточняющих ответов правильно или добавлять обновления в исходный вопрос или делать уточняющие комментарии: это соответствует формату форума.

Comment: спасибо за разъяснение, буду знать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел решение:

при попадании \r в парсер яваскрипта хром давал ту ошибку, в отличие от остальных браузеров. часть описаний, выводимых из базы данных в переменную $DESC, были скопированы откуда-то и содержали этот непечатаемый символ, на котором и спотыкался хром)

решение - убрать \r из строки.

Спасибо всем, кто помогал.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
$DESC = 'test';

echo "FCKeditorAPI.GetInstance('FCKeditor_DESC').SetHTML('**$DESC**');";
```

Если прокатит, значит проблема в значении `$DESC`, т.е. нужно не `htmlspecialchars`, а `str_replace("'", "\\'", $DESC);`.

Comment: Alex Silaev, первое что сделал еще до вопроса здесь - как раз подставил другое значение, не помогло(
В том-то и дело, что проблема в значении $DESC.
Поэтому и грешил на htmlspecialchars

Comment: @dagen niger поймите ещё раз: телепатов нет. Дайте больше информации. Сделайте как сказал Alex Silaev — подставьте строку test и покажите, какая строка приходит клиенту. Покажите, какая строка приходит клиенту, если не подставлять test, а оставить, как у Вас сейчас. Я ставлю на то, что у вас просто изначально переменная $DESC неправильно заполняется на уровне пхп.

Comment: 2kirelagin

Вот что приходит клиенту и вызывает ошибку:

    FCKeditorAPI.GetInstance('FCKeditor_ANNO').SetHTML('<div><ul><li>Ванна </li><li>Каркас </li><li>6 форсунок (система <b>STANDERT HM</b>)</li></ul><br></div>');

А вот вывод при $DESC = 'test', ошибка не вызывается:

    FCKeditorAPI.GetInstance('FCKeditor_ANNO').SetHTML('test');

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, фрагмент кода, в котором присваивается значение переменной data. И все фрагменты, где эта переменная каким-либо образом используется\изменяется. И отвечайте, пожалуйста, на комментарии комментариями, а не новыми ответами на свой вопрос :).

Comment: А, и ещё. Каким именно образом вы узнали, что клиенту приходят именно эти значения строк? Проблема, наверняка, кроется в кавычках…

Comment: в комментариях нету форматирования)
переменная получается от XHR и тут же в eval:

var onSuccess = function(data)
{
  eval(data);
  unset_loading_div();
}
$.ajax({
  url: ".....",
  data: "",
  dataType: "text",
  type: "GET",
  success: onSuccess,
  error: onError,
  cache: false
})

Ошибка получается не при всех описаниях из базы, хотя на первый взгляд описания аналогичны. Думаю на косяк в Хроме уже.

Comment: узнал просто посмотрев консоль Хрома и включив трекинг ресурсов.
да и вручную делал запрос этот, посмотрев текст выводящийся в браузер.
в оригинале нету кавычек( да и экранировал их уже

Comment: В V8-то вряд ли косяк… Тогда уж больше похоже на проблему в CKeditor. Посмотрите исходник SetHTML — может, там что-то кроется…

Answer (score 1):

О! Возникла теория.

Если Вы используете xhtml, то тег `<br>` необходимо закрывать: `</br>`.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">

Comment: Как я понимаю, CKeditorAPI сам преобразует полученный html-код в DOM-дерево внутри своего поля. Так что надо ещё чтобы он знал об этом :). Думаю, остаётся только поэкспериментировать с разными значениями, чтобы понять, что именно ему не нравится…

Comment: Поправка: не <br></br>, а <br />

Comment: Блин, вечно у меня с этим проблема )))